# ASP.NET Web API 2.2 OWIN with mixed authentication JWT and SAML

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, jwt, owin, saml

We have a WebAPI that needs to service different client apps, each one using different authentication mechanisms. One web app client will authenticate using SAML and then pass a SAML based token to the WebAPI. Another one will be using an OpenID Connect token for authentication.

We need to be able to digest both types of tokens in our WebAPI, validate them and authenticate them. Could anyone shed some light on how this could possibly be achieved? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What IDP are you using?

Some IDP e.g. ADFS can be configured to pass JWT tokens on a SAML connection.

SAML wasn't really meant for web API. You could e.g. authenticate using SAML / OIDC and then use the client credential flow to the web API which simply relies on a secret key. That would not have user context though.

Comment: Thanks. In the end we've decided to with OIDC all the way. It was proving too difficult to handle both OIDC and SAML in the same app.